# How do I throttle in jQuery only on a certain condition, and execute immediately otherwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this jQuery plug-in](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for throttle support.

I have a text input variable called `textbox` set as follows, which will execute `someFunction` at most once every second:

```
textbox.keypress($.throttle(1000, someFunction(e)));
```

However, I want `someFunction` to execute immediately if the key pressed is the **enter** key. I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textbox.keypress(function(event) {
  if(event.which == 13){
    // Enter key has been preseed. Do something.
  } else {
    $.throttle(1000, function(){
      someFunction(event);
    })
  }
});
```

Keep in mind what you're passing for callbacks. Both 'someFunction' and '$.throttle' are being invoked directly, with their return values being passed as callbacks. To avoid this, wrap the functions in a function (lambda) as I have done above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have in your code a handler for the 'ENTER' keypress and abort the `$.throttle` if that is the case. Can you paste more of your code maybe to give us a better idea of what to work with?